# Unable to retrieve full http headers for a page

Tags: php, http, curl, http-headers

I am trying to get some stock information from a suppliers page, using a http request. I tried this using cUrl (it works with most sites) but with this one I get an asp.net error (that is hidden to me) - if I try viewing the headers for the site using LiveHTTPHeaders (firefox plugin) - It retrieves only some basic header information. I'm wondering what the problem is. This is the site [www.toolbank.com](http://www.toolbank.com/)
The code I'm using is php

```
if(!function_exists("curl_init"))
    die("cURL extension is not installed");

$ch = curl_init("http://www.toolbank.com/");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$r = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);  

echo $r;
```

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/php-34/getting-response-header-php-curl-request-590248.html

Answer (score 2):

Add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);`.